Bash: build command string with quotes and invoke it directly
In bash, this sequence doesn't work the way I thought it would:
> command="echo \"foo bar\""
> $command
"foo bar"

Using eval instead:
> eval $command
foo bar

This does what I want, but I would prefer not to use eval. Is there any way to formulate the expression "foo bar" such that the direct invocation $command sends the single intended argument to echo, instead of 2 half-quoted arguments?
For context, the script is a simple driver for compiler benchmarking, making it easy to experiment with various compiler options and organize the results for later analysis. There is no presentation factor to be accounted for, only the correct passing of arguments to the compiler, and correct naming of output file paths. Missed quotes lead to errors, whereas superficial factors like spaces are discarded by the compiler frontend and have no effect on the results.

Can you elaborate on why you need to do this? In general, it won't be reliable, e.g., with command="echo \"foo     bar\"", you'll only have one space between foo and bar, not five, with either approach.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: updated the question with context and objectives.

Remember that spaces aren't just for presentation. Consider a filename with multiple consecutive spaces in it.

Variables hold data. Functions hold code. Don't put code inside variables! See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for the issues and in particular https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time how to do what you need to do to build a command on the fly.

This does it, but still uses eval:
command='echo "foo bar"'
eval $command

Now, here it is without eval:
command=("echo" "foo bar")
"${command[@]}"


Thanks, I hadn't though about using an array to avoid ambiguous delimitation. It may take some significant changes in the scripts, but I'll give it a try and see if that resolves the issues.

While the array approach is the best way to do what you want (build a shell command equivalent to a parsed and cleaned input line), to answer the question asked you can use a function:
my_function(){ echo "foo bar"; }

command=my_function

$command # executes echo with one argument containing foo bar 

However in 48 years of Unix usage/programming I've never encountered a case where this was appropriate.
